# syntax error at or near "%" using sql and python

Tags: python, postgresql

I was trying to do some postgresql queries using python.

```
def find_recipe(self, recipe_name):
    cursor = self.conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
    query = """SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE lower(name) like '%%%s%%'""" % recipe_name.lower()
    cursor.execute(query)
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    return records
```

but when I do unit test

```
def test_find_recipe(self):
    recipes = self.service.find_recipe('sandwich')
    self.assertEqual(len(recipes), 2)
    recipes = self.service.find_recipe("';DROP TABLE recipe_ingredient;COMMIT;")
    self.assertEqual(len(recipes), 0)
    self.assertEqual(22, self.query("select count(*) from recipe_ingredient")[0][0])
```

it has error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "restaurant_test.py", line 40, in test_find_recipe
    recipes = self.service.find_recipe("';DROP TABLE recipe_ingredient;COMMIT;")
File "/Users/alice/Desktop/Database System/homework_3.py", line 25, in find_recipe
    cursor.execute(query)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/extras.py", line 144, in execute
    return super(DictCursor, self).execute(query, vars) 
ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "%" LINE 1: ... lower(name) like '%';drop table recipe_ingredient;commit;%'
```

Comment: Are you deliberately trying to use SQL injection on yourself? I'm not clear on why you would write a query using string formatting, and then have a unit test to see whether the vulnerability that you wrote into the query results in injection.

Comment: I mean that quite seriously. Are you doing this as an exercise? It seems pointless to answer the question to fix the string formatting approach if your intention is not to test whether you succeeded in SQL injection as an exercise in unit testing. Please clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: This is a course exercise. The unit test is to test whether I have prevented the injection.

Comment: What steps have you taken to prevent the injection other than a syntax error? Your `assert` comes too late, the change is committed if your syntax was correct to accept legitimate queries too.